# downgrading g++ after changing version

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c++11, lambda

So previously i tried to compile a lambda expression in c++, my default compiler was gcc-4.4 and as you know it doesn't support lambda expressions, so i tried to install a newer version of gcc-4.7, the installation worked successfully but after that i couldn't compile any of my programs.

i tried to recover the previous version of gcc but update-alternatives doesn't work for me.

-errors:

```
    In file included from /usr/local/include/htmlcxx/html/ParserDom.h:5:0,
             from urlServer.cpp:7:
    /usr/local/include/htmlcxx/html/tree.h:118:21: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
    urlServer.cpp: In lambda function:
    urlServer.cpp:148:29: error: ‘urlHash’ is not captured
    urlServer.cpp:148:38: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning            'void' [-fpermissive]
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-         gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/algorithm:63:0,
               from urlServer.cpp:5:
     /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux- gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of  ‘_InputIterator std::__find_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate,           std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator =   std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >; _Predicate =     writeAllLinks(std::list<std::basic_string<char> >)::<lambda(const string&)>]’:
     /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-    gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4490:41:   required from ‘_IIter       std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter =   std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >; _Predicate =        writeAllLinks(std::list<std::basic_string<char> >)::<lambda(const string&)>]’
     urlServer.cpp:148:39:   required from here
     usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux- gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_algo.h:146:7: error: void value not   ignored as it ought to be
```

i'm using debian

**question** : how can i recover the previous version of gcc?

i know this question is already asked but i couldn't find the answer and i tried all what i could, thanks;

Comment: When you say that you "couldn't compile any of my programs", can you please elaborate on that? What errors do you get? Maybe it would be easier to help you fix this problem than going back to the old compiler?

Comment: Your title suggests a different question that what is actually asked (new compiler "doesn't work" vs. downgrading to old compiler).

Comment: ty for your help guys, i updated the question and put the errors i got into it; htmlcxx is a library to extract url from html file.

Comment: The first error (about `ptrdiff_t`) is because of a change in the C++ library in 4.6. See [this text here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/porting_to.html) (easily found by a simple search) for what changed and hints on how you can fix it. The second error is because something in your code, and we can't help you with that unless you show your code.

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/bin/g++ --version`?

Comment: it shows 4.4.5, and i just installed the 4.7 version , i just realized the 4.7 version isn't installed like i wished, but i think while i was intalling the 4.7 version some files changed, and that caused the error.

Comment: It's not installed as a system compiler (you probably didn't use the Debian package manager to install it) so it's installed in `/usr/local` instead of in `/usr`. However, I would bet that it's installed correctly where it is, you just have to make a small change (look at my previous comment, and follow the link).

Comment: that is working ty @JoachimPileborg, i included <cstddef> and it works but, when i execute the program, it says the following:
       
        ./urlServer: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./urlServer)
        ./urlServer: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./urlServer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Simply install the package again with your package manager of your linux distribution. There should also be something like repair package or other similar options in your tool. Don't forget that you need a valid binutils/gcc/libc/g++/libg++ combination. Maybe your distribution contains a meta package for development, which contains all the needed packages.

2) You can install multiple versions of the compiler in parallel.
Simply you have to provide --prefix= to your configure options. I use
/opt/linux-gnu-gcc4.x.x for the versions. Using the /opt path is common practice to not collide with packages of your distribution.

3) The problem, that you could not compile any program at all is not a good problem description. For me it sounds that you have a mixed set of library header to incompatible headers problem. Nobody can understand what you do without a much more detailed error description. But you should start with 1)